# Regex: Remove everything except allowed characters. how?

Tags: c#, regex

If I have string such as 'xktzMnTdMaaM", how to remove everything except 'M' and 'T' - so the resulting string is 'MTMM' ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 22):

```
var input = "xktzMnTdMaaM";
var output = Regex.Replace(input, "[^MT]", string.Empty);
```

and if you wanted to be case insensitive:

```
var output = Regex.Replace(input, "[^mt]", string.Empty, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: +1 for the first solution, but I'm pretty sure the regex *has* to be case sensitive.  Otherwise the expected result would have been `tMTMM`.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Darin's answer, you could solve this differently using LINQ if you wanted:

```
string.Concat("xktzMnTdMaaM".Where(c => "MT".Contains(c)))
```

Comment: This is nice and functional, but be aware that your function will be generating the string "MT" for every character in "xktzMnTdMaaM". Which is gonna be pretty slow. You might be saved by interning though.

Comment: Literal strings *are* interned, so this would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

From your problem description using regular expressions sound pretty much overkill. You could just roll a manual solution like so:

```
    public static string RemoveNonMTChars(string str)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
        {
            if (str[i] == 'M' && str[i] == 'T')
            {
                sb.Append(str[i]);
            }
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Is there any backside to using Regex's?